# Identical Excel Macro works correctly on Windows 10 but not Windows 11

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small macro that reorganizes data and makes it into a Table so I can add slicers to it for display purposes. This macro runs without issue on my personal PC (Windows 10), but does not run correctly on my work laptop (Windows 11). When it hits this step when running on my work machine, it throws a 400 error:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A:$M"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
```

I have enabled macros on my work machine in the Trust Center settings. Stepping through the first dozen or so steps in the macro all work fine. Why does this macro seemingly only work on one device?

Edit: The Windows 10 machine runs Excel version 2310, and the Windows 11 machine runs 2309 -- if that matters.

Comment: If you upgrade to version 2311 in win 11, do you still face the issue?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I do not have the ability to update the win11 machine

Comment: The thing is Error 400 can happen because of many reasons. Does your code just crash or do you see any error message?

Comment: Also can you test something for me. Instead of `ActiveSheet` can you use the actual sheet name or the code name? For example  `Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheet1.Range("$A:$M"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"` **Ensure you fully qualify the range object as well**

Comment: What are the respective releases of Excel and build versions? MS Office can be a devil for "interesting" behaviour when moving code between different releases (particularly in the backwards direction). I'd be very surprised if the OS version was even relevant here. The fix might even be as simple as transplanting the source code as text into a fresh module on the older Excel version that you have at work.

Comment: @MartinBrown it's 2310 on my Win10 machine and 2309 on the Win11 machine -- however pasting the code into a new module did not solve the problem

Comment: @SiddharthRout the solution that worked for me was specifying ActiveSheet.Range (Sheet1 did not work). That seemed to resolve the problem

Comment: `Sheet1` is a sample codename. You have to replace it with the actual sheet code name :) BTW it is very important to fully qualify your objects :)